# An error occurred while installing mini_racer (0.2.6), and Bundler cannot continue. Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ubuntu-20.04

At global scope:

```
cc1plus: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-self-assign’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1plus: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-parentheses-equality’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
cc1plus: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’ may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
```

make: *** [Makefile:212: mini_racer_extension.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Installed openssl-1.1.1q, did not help

Comment: If you have a problem installing a certain software, ask the maintainers.